# How to add archiving functionality?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I added a button to the more menu

```html
<act_window name="Archiver"
    res_model="my.model"
    src_model="my.model"
    key2="client_action_multi" 
    view_mode="tree" target="new" 
    view_type="tree"
    id="act_new_sub_menu" />
```

How can I add functionality to this button ?

I tried to create a `file.xml` and I added it to the `__manifest__.py`

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
        <template id="assets_backend_custom" name="custom assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
            <xpath expr="." position="inside">
             
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/my_module/static/src/js/journal.js"></script>
            </xpath>
        </template>
</odoo>
```

and I created `journal.js`

```html
odoo.define('my_module', function (instance) {



});
```

the functionality I wanna add is like the one we find on `hr.view_employee_form` : `toggle_active`

the selected records shoud be not active once I click the button Archiver

but til here I don't know what should I do

Comment: What fonctionality you are talking about describe it

Comment: the functionality I wanna add is like the one we find on hr.view_employee_form : toggle_active